# How to name bars when using eclplot?

Tags: graph, stata

I use the data below to plot estimates with confidence limits:

```
clear

input year beta ci5 ci95 pvalue
1999  0.390337619 -0.876345001  1.657020238 0.527644768
2001 -0.281463106 -1.14277483   0.579848618 0.503264501
2003 -0.753077604 -1.49646223  -0.009692978 0.047349224
2005 -0.295911126 -0.735095768  0.143273516 0.175219436
2007  0.976340177  0.206120956  1.746559398 0.015560029
2010  0.080218534 -0.428463191  0.588900259 0.745605829
2012  0.021721372 -0.61379414   0.657236884 0.943868989
2014 -0.05203667  -0.658245394  0.554172054 0.859691155
end
```

I do so using the *community-contributed* command `eclplot` and the code that I run is the following:

```
eclplot beta ci5 ci95 year, eplot(bar) estopts(barwidth(0.25)) title("Portfolio") ///
rplottype(  rspike) estopts2(bcolor(black)) ytitle("alpha (b.p.)") xtitle(" years") ///
yline(0,lstyle(foreground))  xline(2007, lcolor(blue))
```

How can I add the p-value above the corresponding bar?

I would also like to draw a thick reference line (light gray) for year `2007`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
generate a = 2
generate b = round(pvalue, .001)

levelsof year, local(allyears) clean

eclplot beta ci5 ci95 year, eplot(bar) estopts(barwidth(0.25))  ///
title("Portfolio") rplottype( rspike) estopts2(bcolor(black)) ///
ytitle("alpha (b.p.)") xtitle("years") yline(0,lstyle(foreground)) ///
xline(2007, lcolor(gs9) lwidth(thick)) addplot(scatter a year, mlabel(b) ///
msymbol(i) mlabposition(6)) xlabel(`allyears')
```